# Некликабельные кнопки Unity

Tags: unity3d

Я новичок в Юнити и делаю простенькую игру. Добавил три новые кнопки и все не работают. До этого создавал кнопку она работает и в ней ивент систем. Все находятся в одном канвасе
[image]
Кнопки - useG1, useG2, useG3; текст(количество) - G1Text, G2Text, G3Text; картинки -  G1, G2, G3. Отключаю все эти элементы с помощью .SetActive(true);/.SetActive(false);
[image]
Не работают кнопки useG1, useG2, useG3.

Comment: Всегда хотел узнать: какая сила побуждает людей писать слово элементы через Е?

Comment: На вашем скриншоте не представлен ни один компонент из перечисленных...

Comment: @МаксимФисман, например не русско-язычных - родной язык? Ну или школа.. не научила...

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.